# display all products with "attribute value = 1" by single click

Tags: attributes, url, catalog-price-rules

we use catalog price rules to give discount for all products.

we have 1000 products in a site. i have to give 50 % discount for 200 products.

what i did is i created an attribute "my_attribute" and gave value = 1 for all 200 products.

after that all 200 products in a site got 50 % discount.

now i have to display all 200 products with one "click url".

as we have some 20 categories in our site, those 200 products are in all 20 categories.

how to give a link for "attribute" , means if we click on one image, it should display all 200 products with

attribute value = "1 "

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products).
It allows you to create product list pages via rules.
So you can create product lists in the same way you create a discount rule.
Even better, If you already had a catalog rule, the extension will add a new button in the catalog rule edit page called `Create products rule` that will copy your discount rule into a products page rule. All you have to do is save it after that.
The extension will add a top menu link to the list of your products. The list of products come with layered navigation, sorting and paging.
[Full documentation can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki)

Comment: is there something like this for Magento 2 ?

Comment: I don't have one.